# Fullwidth slider using background image Flexslider WordPress

Tags: plugin-development

I'm hoping someone can help, I have created a slider plugin using Flexslider that works using custom post types etc. Anyway, it all works great except, I want to set the image as the background of Flexslider not contained within the li. I just can't seem to understand why the syntax is wrong. If someone could help that would be great. Here's what I have so far. Example [here](https://sculptureqode.com/) of what I want to achieve. Basically I need to keep a fixed height and crop the image as it breaks down so it doesn't end up being tiny on mobile like flexslider normally is. I also need it to zoom as the screen size is increased so it doesn't pixelate.

```
   <?php 
// Function used to display slider
function cs_get_slider(){

    $cs_slider= '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';

                query_posts( array( 
                         'post_type' => 'slider-image',
                         'posts_per_page' => 10000 ) 
                 ); 

    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $img= get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID());
    $caption =  caption_content();      

    $cs_slider.='<li style="background: url('<?php echo $background_image['url'] ?>')">'.$img.'<div class="banner-caption meta">'.$caption. '</div></li>';

    endwhile; endif; 
    wp_reset_query();
    $cs_slider.= '</ul></div>';

    return $cs_slider;
}

function cs_slider_shortcode(){
    $cs_slider= cs_get_slider();
    return $cs_slider;
}  
add_shortcode('slider', 'cs_slider_shortcode');
?>
```

This is where it all falls apart.

```
$cs_slider.='<li style="background: url('<?php echo $background_image['url'] ?>')">'.$img.'<div class="banner-caption meta">'.$caption. '</div></li>';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code, `$background_image` is not defined. You might also want to use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts` Anyway, since WP 4.4, you can use [the_post_thumbnail_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) to get the featured image url within the loop.

Comment: @LuisSanz this seems like it should be an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From WordPress 4.4 onwards, you can use [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url) inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to easily get the featured image source:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);">
    //Your html code
</div>
```

If you need compatibility with releases prior to the 4.4, [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) will do the work. Contrary to what its name suggests, it won't return the image location directly, but an array with the location, the width, the height and its resize value. You need to access the first elements of the returned array:

```
<?php

    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' ); //The second argument is the size

?>
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $featured_image[0]; ?>);">
    //Your html code
</div>
```

Apart from that, you should avoid using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) unless you are sure what you are doing. You can read more on the topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/81084). As an alternative use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) followed by [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) to work normally as if you where within The loop or build your query with a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Lots of great info for me to read too, very informative thanks again!